# How to check programmatically if input contains dot(s)?

Tags: c, for-loop, input, printf

I need to check if user input contains dot and if enter key is pressed. (`Text text text .[Enter]`)

If it does then don't write that line to file and exit, else continue with input and to write line into a file.

Here is what code I have so far:

```
FILE *File;
char *fileName = argv[1];
char *ptr;
char name[20];

File = fopen(fileName, "r");
scanf("%s", name);
fprintf(File, "%s\n", name);
for (ptr = name; *ptr!= '\0'; ptr++)
{
    if (*ptr == '.')
    {
        printf("Exit");
        fclose(File);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
       // How to make user continue to input and write to file?
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need an else statement, if you can successfully finish the for loop that means there are no dots to be found in the input. whatever you want to do to the file can go after the for loop.

Comment: When `scanf` returns you *lnow* that the user has pressed the enter key, otherwise the `scanf` call would block indefinitely.

Comment: Are you allowed to use function `strchr()` defined in `string.h`?

Comment: https://ideone.com/J9iOj6 go play with it :)

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII Yes, but I need to continue to use scanf if it did not find dot. I need the program to run until it finds the dot. That's why I use else.

Answer (score 0):

Don't close a file you didn't opened it. Use the file **after** the loop that verified that name contains no dot (open it, write in it, and close it), like this:

```
 char *ptr;
 char name[20];
 FILE *f;
 scanf("%s", name);
 printf("%s\n", name);
 for (ptr = name; *ptr!= '\0'; ptr++) {
   if (*ptr == '.') {
     printf("Exit");
     exit(0);
   }
 }
 f = fopen(name,"w"); // open for writing
 if (f==NULL) { fprintf(stderr,"Can't open the file\n"); exit(1); }
 fprintf(f,"Hello"); // write something
 fclose(f); // close after using the file
```

Comment: I write name into the file. fprintf(File, "%s\n", name);

Answer (score 0):

> I need to continue to use scanf if it did not find dot. I need the
>   program to run until it finds the dot. That's why I use else.

As ForeverStudent wrote, *you don't need an else statement*. You just need to wrap the `scanf()` and all the rest in a loop, e. g.

```
while (scanf("%20s", name) != EOF)
{
    …
}
```